# The One We All Love

Tags: wordplay, rebus

Here is an easy Rebus to wake the group and save the day.
Happy Solving!

> Robert Downey Jr. + CMnSiSNi

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer might be

> Man of Steel, http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0770828/

Argument:

> 1. Robert Downey Jr plays in the movie Iron Man, http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0371746/
>  2. carbon, manganese, silicon, sulfur, nickel are standard ingredients for steel alloys, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alloy_steel
>  3. Iron + alloys = steel

Comment: I didn't see him in the cast list. I think more to the point is his involvement here: http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0371746/

Comment: RD Jr is not in Man of Steel. But I do think you should consider the essential element that mixes with the one in you argument. :)

Comment: well, he was not in the cast of Man of Steel. The answer is right. Only the explanation was not.

Comment: Would you call the puzzle easy or elementary?

Comment: Elementary I suppose, working on a rather tough one! Will share soon :)

Comment: @HughMeyers Good lord. Uh, rivers.